# Need help finding why my application does not leave the home screen upon button click (which should take me to a second activity screen)

Tags: android, button, android-intent, android-activity

I have a main activity where the user has 3 list views and 3 buttons displayed. When the user clicks on 2 of the three buttons I want the user to be sent to another screen (another layout). I already have the two other layouts created and the two other classes created.  I am not sure why this is not working. My application reports no errors, no warnings, and I have found that I cannot go through my code step by step because my debugger is not working.

I have an `OnClickListner`(I am currently just testing one button at a time to get the issue fixed) that is linked to the button in the Main Activity `layout.xml android:OnClick`. I have an Intent put in place within the Main Activity that (according to multiple sources and YouTube tutorials) is set up properly and the new activity that the user should be redirected to is linked to the appropriate layout. When I run the application the button click registers (I know this because I have a sound effect in place when the button is pressed) but nothing else happens. Also all of my activities are present in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. And all of the activity files are at the same folder level, all layouts are under res/layout

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // instantiate button
        Button btnClicked = (Button)findViewById(R.id.goal);
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.click);
btnClicked.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, 
ChangeGoal.class));
mp.start();
            }
        });

// method called when set goal button is clicked
    public void setGoal(View view)

    {
        // intent to send user from main activity to the change goal 
activity
        Intent setGoal = new Intent(this, ChangeGoal.class);
        startActivity(setGoal);
    }
}

public class ChangeGoal extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_change_goal);  // connect 
class to the other layout
    }
}

//button from activity_main.xml
<Button
            android:id="@+id/goal"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:text="@string/Set"
            android:onClick="setGoal"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>`
```

Again, I am expecting the button click from the main activity to send the user to a new activity where they need to make a selection and then return to the main activity. Thus far the button click registers (I can hear it since I included some audio already upon the button click) but the application does nothing, I am left on the same screen and the button can be pressed again and again.

Comment: In your setGoal intent instead of this try MainActivity.this or getContext. I think you get context by view.getContext()

Comment: Edit your question and add the contents of your manifest

Comment: @MohammadC there is nothing wrong with using `MainActivity.this`, as that is an instance of `Activity` and `Activity extends Context`. Calling `getContext()` will basically return the exact same thing (in this case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Activity` layout, you have declared this on your `Button`:

```
   android:onClick="setGoal"
```

Then, in code, you have attached an `onClickListener` to the same `Button`. This is wrong. Do either the one, or the other, but not both.

Comment: Wow thanks  David, it makes so much sense now. I appreciate your reply thank you so much.

Comment: Did this fix your problem? If the answer was helpful you should accept it by clicking the green checkmark next to the answer. this removes the question  from the list of open questions and makes it easier for others to find a solution to their similar problems.